# PHP - Setting up main server on WAMP

Tags: php, email, wamp, wampserver

I'm getting the following error when using the mail() function in php ...

**Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "mail.YourDomain.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in**

can somebody advise on how I go about this?

Comment: Well, isn't the error message clear? Make sure you _have_ an smtp server listening where you want to connect to, make sure no firewall is blocking access. Or make sure to change the named settings inside your `php.ini` configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `mail()` function does not actually do the transmission of an email. It just passes you email to a mail server for transmission.

Windows does not have a mail server by default, so there is nothing to pass your email to for it to actually be sent.

Either you have to install a windows based mail server, like [`hMailer`](https://www.hmailserver.com/) **WARNING: It is not a trivial process to set a mail server up** or use a library like `phpMailer` [which can be found here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score -1):

You are probably using localhost; need to use real server.